# Is this a template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <int parameter> class MyClass
```

is the above a template specialization? I don't think so but I'm unsure of it, I didn't know templates could receive arguments as functions.. where do their arguments get stored?

Comment: Where do the arguments get stored? In RAM. During compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameters do not necessarily need to be type names: they can be numbers as well. For example, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) takes a parameter of type `size_t` for the array size.

In your case, the class template takes a parameter of type `int`, which is entirely OK. Here is an example of how you can use such a parameter:

```
template <int param> struct MyClass {
    int array[param]; // param is a compile-time constant.
};
int main() {
    MyClass<5> m;
    m.array[3] = 8; // indexes 0..4 are allowed.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Their arguments are stored within their type information.

No, that is not a template specialization. Have a look at this:

```
template <int, int> class MyClass;         // <-- primary template
template <int>      class MyClass<int, 4>; // <-- partial specialization
template <>         class MyClass<5, 4>;   // <-- specialization
```